# Error in running jmeter through command line

Tags: jmeter

When I'm trying to run `JMeter` from command prompt like the following way:

```
C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin>jmeter -n -t C:\Jmeter\JmeterExamples\GmailThreadGroup.jmx -l log.jtl
```

I'm getting the following error

> An error occurred : Unknown arg: and errorlevel=1 press any key to
>   continue...

how do I resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Look into jmeter.log file

Run java -version and ensure it is a JAVA >= JAVA6

Comment: I'm using java version "1.7.0_79"

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your command line

**C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin>jmeter -n -t GmailThreadGroup.jmx -l log.jtl**

The reason it was causing error, because you have saved your jmx file in jmeter folder itself, so no need to specify the path for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `sh` after jmeter in `sh jmeter sh` command in terminal. (so execute only `sh jmeter`)

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem. I have browsed and tried most of things but no use. Finally tried,

```
jmeter -h
```

in command line (this got executed without any issues) and then I have tried NON-GUI command it ran. Please give a try...